# Why was Carmine happy after he was set on fire in Cowboy Bill's?

Tags: plot-explanation, laverne-and-shirley

In Laverne & Shirley, why was Carmine happy after he was set on fire in Cowboy Bill's?

I don't understand why would he be smiling and happy after almost being burned to death.

I'm specifically referring to this scene.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is a lighthearted comedy, no? I mean, he wasn’t really going to die or seek fatal revenge on those responsible for his hideous burns a la Freddy Kruger, is he?

Comment: Laverne & Shirley was filmed in front of a live audience, like most Sit-Com's of that era.  *Many* times, actors would come on stage expecting the laugh and even reacting to it while they tried to keep a straight face.  There are some absolute classic moments on The Carol Burnette Show where the actors would say an improvised line and crack all the other actors up.